# Can't start tomcat7 in Netbeans 7.1.1

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

I am trying to deploy an empty webapp through NetBeans, via Tomcat 7.

Tomcat is defined in the "Servers"->"Apache Tomcat". I click "Start", and it runs. I can access it via `http://localhost:8080` , and there the standard Tomcat webpage is.

I then switch to "Projects" tab, where resides an empty, newly created "Java Web Application". The class is created correctly:

```
@WebServlet(name = "myProj", urlPatterns = {"/myProj"})
public class myProj extends HttpServlet {
...
```

When I try to access `http://localhost:8080/myProj` , I receive 404 error.
I try to right click the project, and then "Deploy", and then this message pops:
`Deployment error: Starting of Tomcat failed, the server port 8080 is already in use.
See the server log for details.`

Also, from some reason I can't stop the Tomcat server. Pause/Stop options are grayed out.

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: If I try to deploy without starting the server, I get the next status:
Deploying myProj
Waiting for Tomcat...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it.
From some reason NetBeans tried to use proxy, which was defined in IE.

Hm.